# JSON-based Quiz - Distributing SQL result into Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have set of questions and anwsers for my quiz system stored in mysql. My implemented procedure aims to put those questions and answers into multidimensional array and then convert it into json format. But the result does not satisfies me. I'm stuck with the following procedure:

**Code in PHP:**

```
$query = "SELECT s1.id, s1.question, s2.answers, s2.correct
          FROM `questions` s1, `answers` s2
          WHERE s1.id=s2.questionid AND s1.courseid=".$_POST['courseid']."";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die ("<b>Select failed:</b> ".mysqli_error($mysqli));

$final_quiz = array();
$final_quiz['info']['course'] = $_POST['courseid'];
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_quiz)) {
    $final_quiz['quiz']['id'] = $rows['id'];
    $final_quiz['quiz']['question'] = $rows['question'];
    $final_quiz['quiz']['answers']['option'] = $rows['answers'];
    $final_quiz['quiz']['answers']['correct'] = $rows['correct'];
}
// convert to JSON
$json = json_encode($final_quiz);
echo $json;
```

**Expected JSON Output:**

```
{
    "info":{"course":"Some value here"}
    "quiz":[
        {
            "question":"Question number one here?",
            "answers":[
                {"option":"some incorrect answer", "correct":"0"},
                {"option":"a correct answer", "correct":"1"},
                {"option":"another incorrect answer", "correct":"0"}
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

How to organize multidimensional array in order to get above mentioned json structure? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the question ID as the key into the `quiz` array.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_quiz)) {
    $question_id = $row['id'];
    if (!isset($final_quiz['quiz'][$question_id])) {
        $final_quiz['quiz'][$question_id] = 
            array('question' => $row['question'], 'answers' => array());
    }
    $final_quiz['quiz'][$question_id]['answers'][] = 
        array('option' => $row['answers'], 'correct' => $row['correct']);
}
```

Comment: It's brilliant!! And thank you for your hint to use question IDs as keys in json :)